# How to choose in which monitor applications get opened?

Tags: windows, windows-10, multiple-monitors

I have windows 10, two monitors, extended mode. I have picked my second monitor as my primary monitor but applications still get  opened on my laptop's monitor and I have to drag them to the other monitor.

Comment: I have found similar questions on this site that are 5 or 8 years old, so perhaps useless today.

Comment: It’s mainly up to the application. There’s not universal solution.

Answer (score -2):

This video may give you some points.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1w7aOUgq8eQ

Comment: Link-only answers are frowned upon. Please cite *all* content needed to answer the question. External resources may go away, your answer needs to stay complete.